# Create animated gifs in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm looking for something like [gif.js](https://jnordberg.github.io/gif.js/) that will run in React Native to layer images and text to create animated gifs.

Are there any libraries that will that? Or any way to render a canvas in React Native to make it work?

Comment: Did you ever find something?

Comment: No. I ended up making a aws lambda function to do it server side, with mixed results.